# Limits of a function using rational and irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let,

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}x^2,&x\in\mathbb Q\\x^3,&otherwise\end{array}\right.$$

What is the limit as $x$ goes to $0$? To $1$? Show that the limit as $x$ goes to $a$, when $a$ is not $0$ or $1$, does not exist.

So I know the limit is $0$ and $1$ as $x$ goes to $0$ and $1$, respectively.  I can see how if $a$ was negative, then $f(x)$ would not converge as $x$ goes to $a$.  But I'm not sure how to show if $a$ was positive? If I can show that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in a deleted neighbourhood of $a$ approaches $a$ but $f(\{x_n\})$ diverges then the limit does not exist.

Comment: How did you show that this is the case for $a < 0$?  I think you can modify this proof to come up with something for every $a$ not equal to $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$x^2=x^3 \iff x^2(x-1)=0 \iff x=0 \text{ or } x=1$$

Answer (score 0):

If you construct a sequence ${x_n}\to a$ where every other element is rational and the others irrational, it should be quite simple to see that $f(x_n)$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2 = x^3 $, then $x = 0$ or $x = 1$. Everywhere else, there are points arbitrarily close with two different values for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{x_n\}\to a$ be a sequence in rationals.

Similarly, $\{y_n\}\to a$ be a sequence in irrationals.

**Then** $f(x_n)\to \text{_?}$ and $f(y_n)\to \text{_?}$. What can you conclude? **(Stefanos gave you a good hint)**